# Can methods deny wrong types for Vector2 & Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If i have a method:

```
public void SetPosition(Vector3 position){
   // do stuff
}
```

And i pass a Vector2, why does it still allow it  and auto convert this to be (x,y,0) ?

Is there any way to have the method be more strict and error and not auto convert the vectors? I keep doing this mistake once in a while without realising and get bugs that take me a while to work out the mistake.

Why does C# even allow the programmer to be able to do this when passing arguements?

Comment: Is `Position` your method? Or is it part of unity?

Comment: it was more pseudo code for the question.

Comment: Well I was wondering if it's code that you can change. Could it be `void SetPosition(Vector2Wrapper v)`? That's about the only way to enforce something here. You change to types that don't convert between each other..

Comment: Is Vector2Wrapper a built in type?

Comment: No its something I made up for the purposes of asking what exactly can you change. Obviously you can't change Vector2 or Vector3 themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fix this, because the library that you are using supplies a conversion.

Unity defines an implicit conversion operator for `Vector2` documented [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html):

> Converts a `Vector2` to a `Vector3`.
>
> `Vector2`s can be implicitly converted to `Vector3` (`z` is set to zero in the result).

This is consistent with your observation: the call to your method `Position` is done in two steps - first, `Vector2` is converted to `Vector3` with `z` set to zero, and then the result is passed to `Position`.

There is a trick that you can use to defeat the conversion operator, but it makes your code less readable, so I recommend against it. The idea is based on the fact that C# will not apply two implicit conversion operators to satisfy a method call, so you can do this:

```
class Vector3Wrap {
    private readonly Vector3 v;
    private Vector3Wrap(Vector3 v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public static implicit operator Vector3Wrap(Vector3 v) {
        return new Vector3Wrap(v);
    }
    public static implicit operator Vector3(Vector3Wrap w) {
        return w.v;
    }
}

public void SetPosition(Vector3Wrap positionWrap){
    Vector3 position = positionWrap;
   // do stuff
}
```

Now the call to `SetPosition(myVector3)` will succeed because `Vector3Wrap` will be created implicitly, but the call `SetPosition(myVector2)` will fail, because there is no implicit conversion from `Vector2` to `Vector3Wrap`.

Comment: So C# has no way to force an exception to this behaviour ?

Comment: Noting that the above "trick" works only if you can add a new `SetPosition()` method to make the call ambiguous. Otherwise, the compiler has no trouble deciding which implicit conversion to choose. If you can add a new `SetPosition()` method, you can just add one to match the unconverted type and throw an exception in there, as in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44014288) that was posted.

Comment: @PeterDuniho From OP's "I have a method" I concluded that he has full control over that method, including the change its parameter type. The other answer provides a working solution, but its only shortcoming is that the error happens only at run-time, not at compile time.

Comment: _"From OP's "I have a method" I concluded that he has full control over that method"_ -- yup, and maybe he does. There's not enough context in the question to know for sure. But if they are forced to keep the original method instead of replacing it with a different parameter type, adding an overload would work where the above would not. This may not matter to the OP, but may well matter to the next person who comes across this Q&A looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what library defines Vector2 and Vector3 classes, but I expect there is an implicit [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators). This behavior has been implemented by the library that defines those classes.

One possible solution is to define a second Position method that accepts Vector2 and throws:

```
public void Position(Vector2 position){
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: I think they are part of unity engine. But is there any way to tell the method not to do the conversion, like have exceptions to it?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot override an implicit conversion operator.

Comment: If you add `[Obsolete]` to the method you can also get compile time warnings/errors.

Answer (score 2):

> why does it still allow it and auto convert this to be (x,y,0) ?

The reason is that the author of the Vector2 struct wrote an implicit conversion to Vector3. Since this is part of the Unity3d engine, you can't really change that.

> Is there any way to have the method be more strict and error and not auto convert the vectors?

There is no compiler option to turn implicit conversions off.

> Why does C# even allow the programmer to be able to do this when passing arguements?

It allows the author of the type to define conversions that are "natural" that users don't want to have to think about. Now "natural" is a matter of perspective. I agree when you think they aren't natural they become very painful, so library authors have to be careful about them. There are [guidelines for implicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229033(v=vs.100).aspx). Since it seems that Unity3d defines implicit conversion from Vector3 to Vector2 discarding the z component, they are not conforming to them, which is an unfortunate design decision. However this is not even the conversion you've got an issue with. Either way you are stuck with this library as it is.

If I really wanted to enforce that one should not haphazardly convert to Vector3, I would probably write some kind of wrapper type and use that. A very basic implementation would be

```
struct MyVector2
{
    private Vector2 _value;

    public MyVector2(Vector2 v) 
    {
        _value = v;
    }

    public Vector2 Value { get { return _value; } }

    public Vector3 ToVector3()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector2(MyVector2 v)
    {
        return v.Value;
    }
}
```

So this wrapper would be around a Vector2. It would allow implicit conversion to Vector2 for use with whatever built in methods accept that, but to pass to a Vector3 you could use the ToVector3 method. Note that the Value is still implicitly convertible so be careful with it. Also this way you would not have to modify SetPosition in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, implicit conversion can't be prevented as it's built into UnityEngine. However, you can still prevent bugs from this behavior by adding an overload of the method that accepts the unwanted type and throws an exception:

```cs
public void SetPosition(Vector3 position) {
   // do stuff
}

public void SetPosition(Vector2 position) {
    throw new System.Exception("Implicit conversion not allowed");
}
```

If you accidentally pass in a `Vector2`, the overload is automatically used because it's a better match, and you're notified about doing something that can  lead to unexpected results.